# Prototype inheritance. obj->C->B->A, but obj.constructor is A. Why?

Tags: javascript

```
var print = function(text){
  document.write(text);
  document.write("</br>");
}

var A = function(){
}
A.prototype.name="A";

var B = function(){
}
B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.name="B";

var C = function(){
}
C.prototype = new B();
C.prototype.name="C";

obj = new C();
print(obj.name);
print(obj.constructor.prototype.name);
print(obj.constructor == A);
```

This code gives next output:

```
C
A
true
```

Why obj.constructor here is A and not C ?

Comment: The constructor property is defined in the prototype object, and when you assign it you assign all its members. Any members you want to have different values must be defined, or you will inherit constructor, toString, valueOF, and whatever else theprototype contains.

Comment: Thanks, I realized this already

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As seen in [this code sample](http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html), you have to manually reset the `.constructor` property when using inheritance, or your constructor is being overridden when you call `new A()` or `new B()`:

```
B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.constructor = B; // need this line to fix constructor with inheritance
```

Here is a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/93Msp/.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting - any idea why this is desirable behaviour?

Comment: Given that OO in JavaScript is one big hack, things like this are to be expected.

Answer (score 4):

To make a clear picture:

In the chain

```
 obj->"new B()"->"new A()"   // where obj is the same as "new C()"
```

only `"new A()"` object has property `constructor`. All the other objects get `constructor` property from the prototype chain.

In the code:

```
 var A = function(){
 }
 A.prototype.name="A";
 // A had not create "constructor" property for "new A()" 
 // so, looking at the prototype
 // According to ECMAScript spec 13.2.10
 // A.prototype.constructor == A
 // thus
 // "new A()".constructor == A

 var B = function(){
 }
 B.prototype = new A();
 B.prototype.name="B";
 // B had not create "constructor" property for "new B()" 
 // looking at the prototype
 // B.prototype is "new A()" 
 // as shown above 
 // "new A()".constructor == A
 // thus
 // B.prototype.constructor == A
 // and at the end
 // "new B()".constructor == A

 var C = function(){
 }
 C.prototype = new B();
 C.prototype.name="C";
 // C had not create "constructor" property for "new C()"/"obj" 
 // looking at the prototype
 // C.prototype is "new B()" 
 // looking up to "new B()".prototype
 // "new B()".prototype is "new A()" as shown above
 // "new A()".constructor == A
 // and finally
 // C.prototype.constructor == A

 obj = new C();
 print(obj.name);
 print(obj.constructor.prototype.name);
 print(obj.constructor == A);
```

So as wrote **mellamokb** we should overwrite(create, if more precise) `constructor` property.

Answer (score 0):

I think this post explains a good deal about constructors in prototype inheritance

http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html

Comment: Indeed. That is the same page I linked.