# Is "Subclass.prototype.constructor = Subclass" needed when inheriting objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototypal-inheritance

Consider the following example where `Student` inherits from `Person`:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.say = function() {
    console.log("I'm " + this.name);
};

function Student(name, id) {
    Person.call(this, name);
    this.id = id;
}
Student.prototype = new Person();
// Student.prototype.constructor = Student;    // Is this line really needed?
Student.prototype.say = function() {
    console.log(this.name + "'s id is " + this.id);
};

console.log(Student.prototype.constructor);   // => Person(name)

var s = new Student("Misha", 32);
s.say();                                      // => Misha's id is 32
```

As you can see, instantiating a `Student` object and calling its methods works just fine, but `Student.prototype.constructor` returns `Person(name)`, which seems wrong to me.

If I add:

```
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;
```

then `Student.prototype.constructor` returns `Student(name, id)`, as expected.

Should I always add `Student.prototype.constructor = Student`?

Could you give an example when it is required ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What it the significance of the Javascript constructor property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012998/what-it-the-significance-of-the-javascript-constructor-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this SO question [Prototype inheritance. obj->C->B->A, but obj.constructor is A. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993716/prototype-inheritance-obj-c-b-a-but-obj-constructor-is-a-why).

It should give your an answer.

---